# Generate PDF with Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, pdf

I'm trying to generate an array with data retrieved from SharePoint (The SharePoint part is ok) in a PDF file with PowerShell but i have literally no idea how to do this.

I want something like this
[PDF to generate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epsDo.png)

Edit (1):

```
# Function to query list item from SharePoint
function Get-Items ($ListName, $BEGIN, $END, $IDUSER) {

    # Init variable as null
    $LibItems = $null
    $BEGIN = $BEGIN.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    $END = $END.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

    $LibItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Query "<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='id_client'/><Value Type='Text'>$IDUSER</Value></Eq><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='date_intervention'/><Value Type='DateTime'>$BEGIN</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='date_intervention'/><Value Type='DateTime'>$END</Value></Leq></And></And></Where></Query></View>"

    # Return value
    return $LibItems
}
```

That's what i get from SharePoint (I didn't query all the fields on purpose).

It gives me an Object.

```
Id    Title                                              GUID                                                           
--    -----                                              ----                                                           
586                                                      cee9a0f7-206b-4240-ac42-fbb04e9c44b0                           
587                                                      cc402248-64cb-4e43-9164-1a42bc893cca                           
588                                                      eec5fc30-2408-42c1-aba2-c545600d9777                           
589                                                      6220ddb9-ad96-4c92-bc63-f57b93be18e2                           
652                                                      8433f5fb-70dc-4f96-904f-5376156d6e3d                           
653                                                      76ef46f4-ee6a-4e34-9244-011d0a6022aa                           
654                                                      d399f517-3fe8-43d0-abc9-6f022d66000c                           
656                                                      3f2e5db9-d122-4275-872d-2c5bbcb9f9db                           
657                                                      69b5a90f-bd8e-4735-beef-e13c7903cc47                           
702                                                      03010fc1-c386-4941-9446-ba67cd840260                           
703                                                      4759b602-07ed-4980-bee4-f4d3af36836a                           
704                                                      322aa276-b690-47c3-a401-60ade7b4f187                           
705                                                      96a0b295-6a55-40cd-9880-e580cefde5f1

System.Object[]
```

I tried iTextSharp but i didn't manage to get it work properly...

Comment: I don't think there is enough information in your question to help you. Share some of your code, for example, what does the structure of the data you are retrieveing from sharepoint look like? What PDF generation libraries have you looked at?

Comment: Install a PDF printer Driver an print your pdf from PowerShell.

Comment: PDFSharp works with powershell - http://www.pdfsharp.net/

Comment: It may be better to make a CSV before and convert it to PDF ?

Answer (score 3):

Copy your Output to a texfile and print as PDF afterwards:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

function ConvertTo-PDF {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, Position = 0)]
        $textDocumentPath
    )

    process {   
        $doc = New-Object System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument
        $doc.DocumentName = $textDocumentPath
        $doc.PrinterSettings = new-Object System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings
        $doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = 'Microsoft Print to PDF'
        $doc.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = $true
        $file = [io.fileinfo]$textDocumentPath
        $pdf  = [io.path]::Combine($file.DirectoryName, $file.BaseName) + '.pdf'
        $doc.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = $pdf
        $doc.Print()
        $doc.Dispose()
    }
}


# Function to query list item from SharePoint
function Get-Items ($ListName, $BEGIN, $END, $IDUSER) {

    # Init variable as null
    $LibItems = $null
    $BEGIN = $BEGIN.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    $END = $END.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

    $LibItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Query "<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='id_client'/><Value Type='Text'>$IDUSER</Value></Eq><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='date_intervention'/><Value Type='DateTime'>$BEGIN</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='date_intervention'/><Value Type='DateTime'>$END</Value></Leq></And></And></Where></Query></View>"

    # Return value
    return $LibItems
}


$libItems = Get-Items -ListName "<listName>" -BEGIN "<Begin>" -END "<End>" -IDUSER "<IdUser>"

$libItems | Out-File -FilePath 'D:\test\test.txt'

ConvertTo-PDF -textDocumentPath 'D:\test\test.txt'
```